# when i update to webpack5, there is a error: configuration has an unknown property 'before'

Tags: webpack-5

when I update webpack 4 to 5, the error exits.

I have a webpackDevServer.js which include the error message 'error'

```
// webpackDevServer.js
module.exports = function(proxy, allowedHost) {
    return {
        before(app, server) {
            if (fs.existsSync(paths.proxySetup)) {
                // This registers user provided middleware for proxy reasons
                require(paths.proxySetup)(app);
            }

            // This lets us fetch source contents from webpack for the error overlay
            app.use(evalSourceMapMiddleware(server));
            // This lets us open files from the runtime error overlay.
            app.use(errorOverlayMiddleware());

            // This service worker file is effectively a 'no-op' that will reset any
            // previous service worker registered for the same host:port combination.
            // We do this in development to avoid hitting the production cache if
            // it used the same host and port.
            // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2272#issuecomment-302832432
            app.use(noopServiceWorkerMiddleware());
        },
    };
};
```

I use the above file in a start.js file, when I run the project, I type `node scripts/start.js`

```
// start.js
...
const createDevServerConfig = require('../config/webpackDevServer.config');
...
const serverConfig = createDevServerConfig(
      proxyConfig,
      urls.lanUrlForConfig
);
const devServer = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, serverConfig);
```

then it throws an error

```
configuration has an unknown property 'before'. These properties are valid:
object { bonjour?, client?, compress?, dev?, firewall?, headers?, historyApiFallback?, host?, hot?, http2?, https?, injectClient?, injectHot?, liveReload?, onAfterSetupMiddleware?, onBeforeSetupMiddleware?, onListening?, open?, openPage?, overlay?, port?, proxy?, public?, setupExitSignals?, static?, stdin?, transportMode?, useLocalIp? }
```

here is my package.json

```
"webpack": "^5.20.2",
"webpack-dev-server": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
"webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.0.4",
"workbox-webpack-plugin": "^6.1.0"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to change `before` to the `onBeforeSetupMiddleware`. Link with migration description from v3 to v4. https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/migration-v4.md

In case, something will change on the migration guide, details are attached below

```
v3:

module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    after: function (app, server, compiler) {
      app.get("/some/path", function (req, res) {
        res.json({ custom: "response" });
      });
    },
  },
};

v4:

module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    onAfterSetupMiddleware: function (devServer) {
      devServer.app.get("/some/path", function (req, res) {
        res.json({ custom: "response" });
      });
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: FYI: for webpack v4.7.0+, the option `onAfterSetupMiddleware` is deprecated (more info can be found in [official doc devServer.setupMiddlewares](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserversetupmiddlewares) and [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70513763/1977012))

Answer (score 0):

fxxk, I'm stupid, when i search some key word (eg: `onBeforeSetupMiddleware`), I found the github of webpack-dev-server which tell the changes in new version 4.0.0 beta. https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/releases

Comment: Yes, change `before` to `onBeforeSetupMiddleware` solved the problem.