# node deprecation warning on terminal

Tags: javascript

i got the following node deprecation error on my terminal after upgrading node upon starting my server.

> (node:5644) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_AFTER_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onAfterSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
>
> (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)(node:5644) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_BEFORE_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onBeforeSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cant load a react app after starting server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70469717/cant-load-a-react-app-after-starting-server)

Answer (score 0):

need to run npm install to install all the dependencies and all the depreciation will be solved