# Cant load a react app after starting dev-server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-scripts, craco

After updating dependencies I got problem with @craco (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco) / react-scripts. Resulting in the error:

> (node:14573) *[DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_AFTER_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE]
> DeprecationWarning: 'onAfterSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated.
> Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option. (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created) (node:14573) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_BEFORE_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE]
> DeprecationWarning: 'onBeforeSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated.
> Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.*

Related issue: [Cant load a react app after starting server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70469717/cant-load-a-react-app-after-starting-server)
This seems to be a issue with the proxy settings in the n**ode_modules/react-scripts/config/webpackDevServer.config.js**

Tried resolving this issue by overriding my craco config.
my current config looks like this:

```
const CracoLessPlugin = require('craco-less');
const path = require('path');
const { EnvironmentPlugin } = require('webpack');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
const evalSourceMap = require('react-dev-utils/evalSourceMapMiddleware');
const redirectServedPath = require('react-dev-utils/redirectServedPathMiddleware');
const noopServiceWorker = require('react-dev-utils/noopServiceWorkerMiddleware');
const fs = require('fs-extra');

module.exports = {
    webpack: {
        plugins: [
            new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
                analyzerMode: 'disabled',
                openAnalyzer: false,
            }),
            new EnvironmentPlugin({
                GIT_COMMIT_HASH: 'local-dev',
            }),
        ],
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/'),
        },
    },
    devServer: (devServerConfig, { env, paths }) => {
        devServerConfig = {
            onBeforeSetupMiddleware: undefined,
            onAfterSetupMiddleware: undefined,

            setupMiddlewares: (middlewares, devServer) => {
                if (!devServer) {
                    throw new Error('webpack-dev-server is not defined');
                }
                if (fs.existsSync(paths.proxySetup)) {
                    require(paths.proxySetup)(devServer.app);
                }

                middlewares.push(
                    evalSourceMap(devServer),
                    redirectServedPath(paths.publicUrlOrPath),
                    noopServiceWorker(paths.publicUrlOrPath)
                );

                return middlewares;
            },
        };
        return devServerConfig;
    },
    plugins: [{ plugin: CracoLessPlugin }],
    eslint: {
        enable: true,
        mode: 'extends',
        configure: {
            extends: 'react-app',
            rules: {
                'react/jsx-pascal-case': 'off',
            },
        },
    },
    jest: {
        configure: {
            moduleNameMapper: {
                '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
            },
        },
    },
};
```

*additional information:
"@craco/craco": "^7.1.0"
"react-scripts": "^5.0.1"
"react": "^18.2.0",*

Any got any clue why this override isn't working?
Thx :)