# How to clear this Deprication warning in Node - 13980

Tags: node.js, reactjs, terminal

onAfterSetupMiddleware option is depricated. Please use the setupMiddlewares option?

I have tried so many solutions and nothing happens

I want to clear this warning in my project

Try running the the script using the the --no-deprecation parameter which will "silence deprecation warnings":

node --no-deprecation script

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70469717/cant-load-a-react-app-after-starting-server  though it isn't advisable to change node_modules directly. There is also an open issue for this, it seems to stem from create-react-app https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/12035