# How to show Electron React application window?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, electron

I have started working on a school project and it is my first time using React, Electron, and pretty much anything related to JavaScript. I've been watching videos to get a basic Electron/React app running, but it only works in the browser when using the URL 'http://localhost:3000'.I also tried running an Electron app without React and it worked fine, so I think the issue is probably related to React. Running 'npm run electron:serve' (more details in package.json file) gives the following result, without an application window showing up. ['npm run electron:serve' results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b14uL.png)

Below is the boiler plate code I have written for my program

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

require('@electron/remote/main').initialize()

function createWindow(){

    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            enableRemoteModule: true
        }
    })

    win.loadURL('http://localhost:3000')
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)


app.on('window-all-closed', function(){


    if (process.platform !== 'darwin'){
        app.quit()
    }
})

app.on('activate', function(){


    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length == 0) createWindow()
```

and below is the package.json file for my project. (with electron:serve and electron:start).

```
{
  "name": "bizi-boardz",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "boostrap": "^2.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "main": "./public/main.js",
  "homepage": "./",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "electron:serve": "concurrently -k \"cross-env BROWSER=none npm start\" \"npm run electron:start\"",
    "electron:build": "",
    "electron:start": "wait-on tcp:3000 && electron ."
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is all the files I currently have in my project. [project file tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1w01.png)

And finally here is a link to an unrelated issue that I was having which made me change a part of a file in the node_modules folder: [Cant load a react app after starting server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70469717/cant-load-a-react-app-after-starting-server).

Sorry if this is a bit of a dump, I don't use StackOverflow often. Let me know if I should provide any other information.